# Why would you bind data to a new form?

Tags: django, forms

In the [Django documentation on Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form), it explains how to pass data to a new form you are creating.

For example

```
data = {'subject': 'hello',
         'message': 'Hi there',
         'sender': 'foo@example.com',
         'cc_myself': True} 
f = ContactForm(data)
```

But why would you ever want to do this? Isn't the whole point of creating a form to solicit new data? If you are putting in the data, why not just enter it directly into the model?

Comment: To display validation info in case of erroneous input.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#using-forms-to-validate-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the idea, the idea is to describe the `Form` API, generally we instantiate the format without passing data to render an empty form in the GET request, and with user's data after user submit the given form. You will write some code like that:

```
if request.method == "GET":
    form = ContactForm()
elif request.method == "POST":
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, as that same documentation says, the *primary* purpose of a form is for validation. So you pass the data to be validated, and the form determines the errors.